# Decimal data not stored correctly in database by doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, informix

Within one of my Symfony applications I encountered a strange behavior of the doctrine ODM. What I'm trying to do is simply saving decimal typed data to our Informix database. Whenever I try to do so everything behind the decimal separator is cropped.

I tried several ways of assigning data such as:

- $position->setFrpProz(1.2345);
- $position->setFrpProz("1.2345");
- $position->setFrpProz("1,2345");

The result in the database is always: 1.0000

This is the yml for the entity:

```
frpProz:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 10
        scale: 4
        column: frp_proz
```

Within Informix the database field is also defined as Decimal(10,4).

I already tried the Doctrine EchoSQLLogger with following results (shortend):

```
"START TRANSACTION"
UPDATE st_frb_mpos SET frp_proz = ?, [...] WHERE [...]
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "1.2345"
                          [...]
}
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "decimal"
                          [...]
}
"COMMIT"
"okay"
```

I really don't know how to solve this. I already tried to upgrade my application from symfony 2.8.? to 3.4.15 - no difference in this topic.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have the ability to access the database using `dbaccess`?   If so, does it report truncated values or does it show (2?) decimal places?  Passing a string like you seem to be doing normally works.  We may have to try debugging with `sqliprint` in due course, but that’s a low-level last resort.

Comment: I made a quick query using `dbaccess` the result is as expected `frp_proz    12,7000`. I'm usually using NetBeans to access the database. If I'm updating rows using the IDE all decimal digits are stored correctly. Even my Symfony-App shows all decimal digits - it just does not store them.

Comment: Are you saying that when you use `dbaccess` to query data entered by Symfony, you don’t get the decimal places, but when you query data entered via `dbaccess`, you do? Or do you get the decimal places on query regardless of how the data was inserted, but Symfony doesn’t show the decimal places?

Comment: The decimal places are displayed in Symfony and `dbaccess`if they are entered by `dbaccess`or an 4GL application running on that database. Whenever I enter data using Symfony the decimal places are all zero no matter if I use `dbaccess` or Symfony to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

you are misunderstanding the meaning of scale.

Taken from the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).

> The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

Because you have specified 10,4 the database is only storing 4 decimal places to the right of the point.

Precision is the total amount of digits to be stored.  So 10,4 would allow you to store values such as `123456.7890`

Hense any value you store will be cropped to 4 decimal places.

Comment: You are right, but I'm not mixing anything up. The precision is 10 and the scale is 4. So the number 1.2345 should be stored als 1.2345 and not 1.0000
Moreover, everything up to 999999.9999 should be saved just fine

Answer (score 0):

Although in Informix you defined the receiving column as DECIMAL(10,4), its acting like you defined it as DECIMAL (10,0) and rounding 1.2345 to 1.0000, so maybe Symfony rounded it to 1.0000 before sending it to Informix?.. That's my suspicion of what's happening because its showing the 4 decimal zero's in Informix, which is a valid value for the precision/scale you defined. So I suggest you research your Symfony frp_proz NumberType field options, such as scale and rounding_mode, to see if the number is being transformed in Symfony.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html

Have you experimented casting it to CHAR before sending to Informix, or defining the Informix column as a FLOAT datatype to see the result?